# In the Docusign API, How do you set the recipient name or email body with more than one word?

Tags: json

when I construct the json payload for creating and sending an envelope document, the emailBlurb and signers.name will only accept a single word. How do you format a string of multiple words for these or any of the values being passed?

when I enter a full name for the value of the signers.name key or for the emailBlurb key, I get an error Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: "  How do you pass a phrase into a value without this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking on many examples on the [official documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/get-envelope-information/), it seems all strings are base64 encoded. Try with that way.

And please specify with more details which version of the API you are using. Java? PHP? etc.